# How do I add removeClass to a selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two menus on a page (see the jsfiddle below if needed... it's responsive so you'll need to minimize the window). Currently when one is opened and you click the other, they both stay open. How would I edit the javascript so when one opens, the other closes? I know I need to add a removeClass but I'm not sure how to implement it. Thanks so much for any help.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jq6sZ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('js');
    var $menu = $('#menu'),
        $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
        $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a');

    $menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
    });

    $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('js');
    var $menu = $('#menu2'),
        $menulink = $('.menu-link2'),
        $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a');

    $menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
    });

    $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a reason why you have the same js code twice?  Was that a copy/paste error?

Comment: @wirey He dosn't the diff is in the id `#menu` and `#menu2`

Comment: You know you can use `$('#menu, #menu2').each(function(){var $menu = $(this);...` instead of duplicating your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether or not the other menu [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) of `active`. For example, in your click event for `menu-link` you would have something like:

```
if($('.menu-link2').hasClass("active")){
    $('.menu-link2').trigger("click");
}
```

Then use [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger a `click` event on the other menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jq6sZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be a lot simpler and shorter, you have 2 docready statements, and you twice set the body class to 'js'. This can be shortened. On the whole, you are a bit limited by the way the HTML is laid out, but there is a way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass('js');

    var $menulink = $('.menu-link, .menu-link2'), 
        $menuTrigger = $('.has-subnav > a');

    $menulink.click(function(e) {
        var menu_to_toggle = $(this).next(); //which menu will this button toggle?
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.not($(this)).removeClass('active'); //remove active class from all menu links, but not this one
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); //toggle active class for this link
        $('.menu.active').not(menu_to_toggle).removeClass('active'); //remove active class from all menus, but not this one
        menu_to_toggle.toggleClass('active'); //toggle active class for the menu
    });

    $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

[See this Fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/HE37E/)

Note: the script does not re-collapse the submenu's.